# How to move caret to a new line with rangy after restoring position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caret, rangy

I am using rangy to manually restore the caret to the position where it previously was before replacing the html of a contenteditable div.

This is the code to restore the caret to it's previous position:

```
 let newText = "I love squares <a href=#> #and </a> circles";
 sel = rangy.getSelection();
 savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(textField[0]);
 textField.html(newText);
 sel.restoreCharacterRanges(textField[0], savedSel);
```

Notice that the | indicates where the caret is at the moment. The caret will be placed back behind the hashtag (#and):

> I love squares #and |
>
> rectangles and circles

But I would like to replace the last line with code to place the caret on the next line after having restored the caret to it's previous position:

> I love squares #and
>
> |rectangles and circles